# angular - savely create and dispose inline web workers

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, web-worker

My use case is that I want to use web workers in angular libraries to run heavy computations.

Since angular [does not support web workers for libraries](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15059) yet, I thought of using [inline web workers](https://medium.com/@dee_bloo/make-multithreading-easier-with-inline-web-workers-a58723428a42) as the service below illustrates. I create 2 inline workers and terminate them after 5 and 10 seconds respectively. In Firefox dev tools I can see that the 2nd and 3rd thread disappear accordingly.

[image]

Now my questions are

1. Does worker.terminate savely dispose of everything, so that I don't need to worry about memory leaks?
2. Does this method of creating web workers has some serious security issues?
3. Is there a way to check all running web workers on chrome dev tool as well?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WebWorkerService {
    constructor() {
        this.create(5000);
        this.create(10000);
    }

    create(terminate) {
        const worker = this.createWorker((data) => {
            postMessage('test');
        });
        worker.onmessage = (e) => {
            console.log('msg', e);
            setTimeout(() => {
                worker.terminate();
            }, terminate);
        };
        worker.postMessage('hi');
    }

    createWorker(fn: (_) => void) {
        const blob = new Blob(['self.onmessage = ', fn.toString()], {
            type: 'text/javascript',
        });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        return new Worker(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No.
3. Yes, in the "source" panel of your dev tools you'll see all the threads initiated by the current tab.

[image: screenshot of the source panel of Chrome's dev tools]

#### But that doesn't mean what you are doing is a good idea.

To start a Worker is a fastidious operation, involving a lot of IO, eating up a lot of memory and which will slow down even the main thread.
[Quoting the specs themselves](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#scope-2):

> Generally, workers are expected to be long-lived, have a high start-up performance cost, and a high per-instance memory cost.

So instead of starting a lot of Workers, start only one and communicate with it so it performs the operations you want it to perform for the whole life of your page. Better have one quite long script idling in the Worker than to start a new computer for every simple arithmetic operation you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the info i needed :)